# laravel error first step

Tags: php, laravel-4

I installed Laravel-4 on my MAC, its all good until i try to do something.
I tried to follow the tutorial on website, which is the **basic route** here http://laravel.com/docs/quick

When i tried to open, its an error with message: Class Route not found on routes.php

I barely use framework PHP, so should i make a class for it or what do they want?

Is there another way to test that i could use the Laravel-4 php , like the hello-world ?

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? I'm not sure if that's required in your case (depends on how you installed Laravel) but you could give it a try

Comment: I'd try @Kryten's, could also be `composer dump-autoload` (note, depending on your Composer installation you may need to replace `composer` with `php composer.phar`).

Comment: 1)i tried to reinstall the composer , i just realized when i put the ( sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/... ) . It said m v: composer.phar no such file or directory

2) So , i tried to make one ( mkdir /usr/local/bin ) . And then it said File exists , but still got the same error on first step. WHen i tried to echo $PATH , it shows me this long list (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm....)

Comment: You can just install composer locally for the project if its not working globally for you. At least till you figure it out.